# Find & Replace part of a file name using a CSV that contains Old and New strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have code that replaces part of a file name if it matches:

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk(r"C:\\Users\\jmcarthur\\Desktop\\Find_Replace\\")
        for filename in filenames)
for path in paths:
newname = path.replace("[FIND_TEXT]","REPLACE_TEXT")
if newname != path:
     os.rename(path, newname)
```

I'm trying to integrate this into a loop, and use a CSV file as the lookup tool instead of having to do 600 'searches' 1 by 1.

I found that i can get close to this with the following code:

```
import os
import csv

IDs = {}
with open('File_Matching.csv','r') as csvfile:
matching = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
for row in matching:
    IDs[row[0]] = row[1]

path = (r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Find_Replace\\")
tmpPath = (r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Find_Replace\\Fixed')
for oldname in os.listdir(path):
if oldname in IDs:
    try:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, oldname), os.path.join(tmpPath, IDs[oldname]))
    except:
        print('File ' + oldname + ' could not be renamed to ' + IDs[oldname] + '!')
```

However, this looks for the whole file name, not just the sub-string im trying to find/replace.

Can someone help with getting the top piece of code integrated with the csv search of the bottom? I'm sure im missing something simple - but i just can't quite crack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were after:

```py
import os
import csv

replace_csv = "replace.csv"
current_folder = "tests"
new_folder = "replaced"

with open(replace_csv, mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    replace_dict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

for file in os.listdir(current_folder):
    full_path = (os.path.join(current_folder, file))
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    for key, value in replace_dict.items():
        if not key in file_name:
            continue
        new_name = file_name.replace(key, value)
        new_file = (os.path.join(new_folder, new_name + file_extension))
        os.rename(full_path, new_file)
```

This will move the files that it modifies from `current_folder` to `new_folder`. You will need to add in your own error handling, for example, if either directory doesn't exist or if the file already exists in the `new_folder` directory.

My `tests` folder contained

```
    a.a
    b.b
    New Text Document.txt
```

My `replace_csv` contained:

```
a,b
b,a
```

After executing, my `new_folder` contained

```
    a.b
    b.a
```

Comment: Thanks Lucan, worked perfectly - will add some checks and balances now.